# Action to deselect every item in a Tab

Tags: openxava

I'm thinking in creating an action to deselect every item in a Tab, even items selected in pages that you are not seeing.
I'll like to know your opinion about this.

I mean: 
If you filter a tab, for example column name start with 'C' and select 2 items and after that you change the filter, column name start with 'X' and select 3 items and after that you clean the filter and apply you'll see all items in the Tab but probably you don't see the items selected. If now you want to change the selection you need to deselect the items selected but, how do you know what items are selected? how do you deselect all items? You can't.

So I'm thinking in creating this action and add it to default actions in list mode.

Comment: Maybe it would be interesting add a select all action too.

Comment: And what about that the check all checkbox select and deselect all the rows (not just the displayed one)?

Comment: The most elegant solution is the button simulating a checkbox in Gmail, in this way you can select all, select rows displayed and also deselect all with one button. @javierpaniza, is it difficult to do?

Comment: The way GMail works seems good, however we have no so many options, just selecting the displayed rows or all rows. So we can just ask if the user wants to select all the rows indicating the total amount of rows, just as GMail. The more difficult thing is to implement  @OnSelectElementAction, though it only aplies to collections.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand well what you say. Do you mean ask the user when he check on the checkbox if he wants to select all rows or not?

Comment: "Do you mean ask the user when he check on the checkbox if he wants to select all rows or not?"

Yes, but in a non-intrusive way. Have a look at GMail, it uses a link inside a message.